# Protect files with a password

Tags: c#, .net

I need to password protect files (with C#). files can be in any format `pdf, txt, xml, excel, word`.

I found out that i could use various 3rd party libraries to password lock PDF files, but not all the other files available out there.

Can someone please direct me with the correct approach to solve this.

In brief when an user double clicks on a file he/she should be asked to enter the correct password to view its content.

Sorry i don't have any code to demonstrate my findings.

Comment: You put a file in a .ZIP file which supports a password for access/unzipping. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607858/how-to-zip-and-unzip-using-password-in-c-sharp-program

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that this is not possible in the general case. For example if the user has `notepad` associated to open `txt` files on his computer, then you cannot possibly expect notepad to prompt the user for a password when double clicking on a txt file simply because the notion of a password is undefined for this program.

That's the reason why you should tackle the problem for each of the file formats. PDF, Excel and Word all support password protected files. TXT and XML do not.

Answer (score 0):

If it's someone else format like PDF, any option you get to do this sort of thing will be theirs. Format like txt don't and will never have such a feature. Easy option would be to zip them up and put a password on that. Note once you've given someone read access they can copy your document to their hearts content. I'd go back to whoever asked for this and ask them what they were trying to do, one bit of social hacking and the entire idea is a waste of resources.

Comment: So what might be the solution for this problem?

Comment: zip? Encrypt the lot and write an app to view them, sort of like a document safe. Spend your resources on something that adds value as opposed to trying to hang on to what value 'you' have...